# Rails ActiveRecord Query: Too slow unless I split it into 2 queries. Why?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My `Post` model `has_many :comments`. And it has a search method with this query:

```
joins{comments.outer}.where{ (title.like_any search_words) | (body.like_any search_words) | (comments.body.like_any search_words) }
```

That gives the desired records: "Find all Posts where the title, body, or any of its comments' body (if it has comments) matches any of the search_words".
The problems is: ***this query takes 8 seconds!*** I can make it run in mere milliseconds if I split it into 2 queries:

```
( where{ (title.like_any search_words) | (body.like_any search_words) }
 + joins{:comments}.where{ comments.body.like_any search_words } ).uniq
```

That gives the same results, only much faster. But it forces the `ActiveRecord::Relation` into an array, so I can't do stuff like `.includes` and `.pagination` afterwards. I really want to keep the result as an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, but I want it to be faster. What would you do?

PS: I'm using Squeel here.

Thanks.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: MySQL (client's existing database)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using rails 4 then query chaining is possible. else what you can do is select the required field as you need to show. and also do the proper indexing for search fields but make sure before and after adding the index please check you performance. 
or another option is write a required sql query. and use it by `find_by_sql` method in rails.

Comment: Query chaining combines queries with "AND", but I need "OR". I could do raw SQL...

Comment: Yes @Arcolye you can write raw sql too

Answer (score 0):

The two seperate queries, imho, will be significantly faster because they are each much simpler and much easier for the database to optimise.

So ideally what one would want is the `union` of those two queries. Unfortunately, afaik, this feature does not exist in ActiveRecord/Arel/Squeel. So you would have to write your own query to solve that.

Of course: I am not sure that if you do the two queries, union, and then distinct, you will not get the same execution speed as the first query.

I generally use postgresql (and would recommend that), but I noticed that MySQL also support [`FULLTEXT` indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html), so you might want to look into that.